# How to have different video popup-s in the same webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, popup

I am working on a HTML page, and I want to have different images, and for each of them a popup video. Using a code (html, css, javascript) I can make this for one video: when I click on my image, a video opens in the same page.
But I need different videos for different pictures, and they all open the same first video. How can I direct each picture to a different video?

I have tried using variables in javascript, to connect the image to a video id, each with their own source (link to the video)
Now I tried to make different javascript functions for each video (numbered 1 and 2)
But they still open the same video

this is the java script code (where I added '1', I added '2' for the other one) (I also tried using the video id)

```
<script>
window.document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = event;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    *lightbox_close1*();
  }
}

function *lightbox_open1*() {
  var lightBoxVideo = document.getElementById(**"V1"**);
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
  lightBoxVideo.play();
}

function *lightbox_close1*() {
  var lightBoxVideo = document.getElementById(**"V1"**);
  document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';
  lightBoxVideo.pause();
}
</script>
```

and this is what I have in html

```
<div id="light">
  <a class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="*lightbox_close1*();"></a>
  <video id=**"V1"** width="600" controls>
      <source src="10 Creamy  Satisfying Pasta Dishes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <!--Browser does not support <video> tag -->
    </video>
</div>

<div id="fade" onClick="*lightbox_close1*();"></div>

<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="*lightbox_open1*();">
  <div class="container">
  <img src="Aperitive.jpg" alt="A" class="image" >
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Aperitive</div>
  </div>
</div>  
  </a>
</div>
```

the other one is just the same but 2 instead of 1, the '**' are just for bolding
(I added image overlay in css)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code around a bit but the concept is the same I think. You want to change the source of the video when you click on another element. In this case an image.

You can put the video in a modal or pop-up window and set it to close on click.  (this function is not included in the example)

All you need to do is to add another element to the unordered list and set the on click function to change to the video with the video element id in the arguments.

Full example below just plug your videos into the video1.mp4 and watch the magic happen.

<=========================================

```
         Edited for clarification
```

=========================================>

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Vid Stuff</title>
        <style>
            ul{
                list-style: none;
                text-align: center;
                width: 50%;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            li{
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 5px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin-right: 16px
            }
        </style>
                <script>

                        //this function takes 2 arguments the video element id
                        //and the video source. 
                        function changeVid(id, video){
                            //set the element for the change
                            var vid = document.querySelector('#' + id + ' source');
                            //change the source of the element
                                vid.src = video;
                            //load the video to play
                                document.querySelector('#' + id).load();
                            //logging purposes to see the change in action (optional)
                            console.log(document.querySelector('#' + id +' source').src);
                        }


                </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="video-wrapper">
                    <video id="myvideo" controls>
                        <source src="video1.m4v" type="video/mp4">
                            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                    </video>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <!-- onclick of user set myvideo <video> to the video source specified -->
                    <li onclick="changeVid('myvideo', 'video1.m4v')" > Cat Video 1</li>
                    <li onclick="changeVid('myvideo', 'video2.m4v')" > Cat Video 2</li>
                </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how/where to use this; I need more than 2 videos.. I have a few images, and I want to be able to click one of them, then a video to open, then I close it; and when I click on another image, a different video to open the same way

Comment: @Ale if I'm still missing the point, maybe you can point me to an example website or something similar that you are trying to achieve.